# Join query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I am trying to implement a query in laravel, but that doesn't give me any result. However, when I try to run the raw query in PHP MyAdmin, I get the desired results

Laravel Query:

```
DB::table('ticket_details')
    ->join('ticket_stages', 'ticket_stages.stage_id', '=', 'ticket_details.stage_id')
    ->join('users_details', 'users_details.user_id', '=', 'ticket_details.assigner_id')
    ->join('client_details', 'client_details.client_id', '=', 'ticket_details.client_id')
    ->join('user_roles', 'user_roles.role_id', '=', 'users_details.role_id')
    ->select('client_details.client_id, client_details.client_name,
        ticket_details.ticket_identifier, ticket_details.ticket_id, 
        ticket_stages.stage_name, ticket_details.assigner_id, 
        users_details.user_name, user_roles.role_name')
    ->get();
```

Raw Query:

```
Select c.client_id, c.client_name, t.ticket_identifier, t.ticket_id, s.stage_name, 
    t.assigner_id, u.user_name, r.role_name 
from ticket_stages s inner join ticket_details t on s.stage_id = t.stage_id 
inner join users_details u on u.user_id = t.assigner_id 
inner join client_details c on t.client_id = c.client_id 
inner join user_roles r on r.role_id = u.role_id
```

What could be the exact problem?

Comment: You can use [toSQL()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) on your Laravel query to verify that it is generating the same SQL that is working for you when you run it in PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel query is not the same as the raw query as it also references ticket_details. This table seems to be missing from the second table. Did you try to run toSQl() as suggested by "Don't Panic" ?

Answer (score 0):

This was my error. A very basic error. Didn't put quotes after each parameter of select clause.

```
DB::table('ticket_details')
                        ->join('ticket_stages', 'ticket_stages.stage_id', '=', 'ticket_details.stage_id')
                        ->join('users_details', 'users_details.user_id', '=', 'ticket_details.assigner_id')
                        ->join('client_details', 'client_details.client_id', '=', 'ticket_details.client_id')
                        ->join('user_roles', 'user_roles.role_id', '=', 'users_details.role_id')
                        ->select('client_details.client_id', 'client_details.client_name', 'ticket_details.ticket_identifier', 'ticket_details.ticket_id', 'ticket_stages.stage_name', 'ticket_details.assigner_id', 'ticket_details.creator_id', 'ticket_details.assignee_id', 'users_details.user_name', 'user_roles.role_name')
                        ->get();
```